# Display PHP array values in loop

Tags: php

I have this array of values

```
$statuses = array(
'pending' => 'Pending', 
'paid' => 'Received', 
'failed' => 'Failed', 
'withdrawn' => 'Paid Out', 
'refunded' => 'Refunded'
);
```

I am then running a foreach loop:

```
foreach (array_reverse($output) as $row) {
    echo $row->status;
}
```

When i echo `$row->status` in my loop, if it is equal to `withdrawn` can it display `Paid Out` (like in my array) ?

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. Unless you're not providing us with enough relevant info, it doesn't really make sense. is `$output` supposed to be `$statuses`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it definitely can. As long as the result of `$row->status` maintains the same as the `key` in `$statuses`

```
echo $statuses[$row->status];
```